Metabase Mysql Connection Error - Client does not support authentication protocol
I am using digital ocean managed mysql database.
The connection is working since last 1 year. Suddenly the issue arrises.
Could not connect to address=(host=*****.ondigitalocean.com)(port=25060)(type=master) : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. plugin type was = 'mysql_native_password'
When I used, mysql 8+ default encryption it returns:
Could not connect to address=(host=*****.ondigitalocean.com)(port=25060)(type=master) : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. plugin type was = 'caching_sha2_password'
No Idea what should I try.
